# xorg.conf monitor layout preferences ignored after upgrading to nVidia+Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, kde, display-resolution

I just built a new PC, installed Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, ran my ansible playbook and rsync'd over my home directory, and transplanted my GeForce RTX 3060... but the `Option "MetaModes"` modeline in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is getting ignored.

Instead of getting a "1280x1024, 1920x1080, 1280x1024" desktop, locked to that resolution so games that fullscreen by changing resolution can't scramble up my windows on first run after install, I get a row of `nvidia-auto-select` where the left-most monitor is to the right of what should be the right-most monitor. (1920x1080, 1280x1024, 1280x1024)

I've confirmed that I am indeed using X11, not Wayland (something I intend to continue to do at least until compositor crash recovery is ironed out), and I tried moving the `Option "MetaModes"` line from `Section "Device"` where it was working perfectly on my 20.04 LTS machine with the same GPU and driver version to `Section "Screen"` where `nvidia-settings` wanted to save it in the preview, but it has no effect.

It's not KScreen2, because I keep that turned off in Background Services to avoid it "helping" by unpredictably jumbling up my Plasma panel-monitor mappings and monitor positions on each reboot, and because the problem is already established at the SDDM login screen.

Looking at `Xorg.0.log`, it appears that the metamodes line *is* getting applied, but then is getting overridden by something.

```
[    20.108] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +3200+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-3: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    20.166] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-3: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    20.252] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-3: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    20.338] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +3200+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[...]
[    44.426] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +3200+0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, View
PortOut=1280x1024+0+0}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
```

How do I fix this? Did Kubuntu 22.04 LTS add some new buggy hotplug helper I need to kill off or blacklist?

Is it even fixable or am I stuck doing something drastic like reaching back to my early 2000s knowledge and writing the entire Xorg.conf setup manually to make it too scared that it'll break something if it tries to autodetect modes I don't want?

**EDIT:** As a stop-gap to make sure I don't need to reshuffle my windows every time I start my system, I put `xrandr --output DP-3 --left-of DP-1` into `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/01-fix-the-damn-ignored-metamodes`. The monitors are still scrambled up at the login screen, but that at least gets them un-scrambled before KDE starts bringing up my desktop.